# Visual Studio 2017 Outputting in Hex

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm just messing around in VS Community 2017 and whenever I debug, the answer is output as below. This happens in two different programs I've debugged.

*ex. Output is 00F911D1 rather than expected value*

[image: Output of code is 00F911D1 rather than expected value.]

This value seems to change with each output. When I run this on another system the code works as expected. Here's the code that I ran that ended in this specific output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double gasPrice;
int avgMPG;
int tankSize;

double CPM()
{
    double math;
    math = (gasPrice * tankSize) / avgMPG;
    return math;
}

int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Please enter the cost of gas without currency => ";
    cin >> gasPrice;
    cout << "Enter the size of your fuel tank to the nearest whole number => ";
    cin >> tankSize;
    cout << "Enter your average miles per gallon as a whole number => ";
    cin >> avgMPG;

    cout << "Your cost per mile is: " << CPM << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

The only information I can find related to this issue is disabling hex output but from what I can tell, mine is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain if this will solve your problem, but you should include parentheses when calling a function. For your example, try using `CPM()` instead of `CPM`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double gasPrice;
int avgMPG;
int tankSize;

double CPM()
{
    double math;
    math = (gasPrice * tankSize) / avgMPG;
    return math;
}

int main()
{
    cout << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Please enter the cost of gas without currency => ";
    cin >> gasPrice;
    cout << "Enter the size of your fuel tank to the nearest whole number => ";
    cin >> tankSize;
    cout << "Enter your average miles per gallon as a whole number => ";
    cin >> avgMPG;

    cout << "Your cost per mile is: " << CPM() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is correct. Not using the parentheses means you are printing the address of that function in memory, because you are using a pointer. Using them means you are printing the return value of the function in question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made some edits to the code that overall reflected your comments. It was a similar conclusion about the memory that I came to shortly after. Again, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it solved. =)